# DownloadManager in Citrix environment isn't working

Tags: android, citrix, android-download-manager, download-manager

I'm working on an app that's only used within a Citrix environment and need to add the DownloadManager to it.  Everything works great until I try testing the app within a Citrix environment.  Downloads seem to kick off and appear to finish but my app fails to receive the results.  I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was something called a Policy Setting within Citrix. I don't have access to this which is why I didn't realize something like a policy setting existed.

When editing your app in the XenMobile App Controller, you must add:

`{action=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE}`

under the *Restricted Open-In exception list* policy section.  This will allow the DownloadManager's broadcast to get through the Citrix barrier for your app to receive.